# I am trying to run my test script using mocha but there is an error of "Reference Error: beforeEach is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

Mocha test Suite gives a reference error and it says "beforeEach is not defined"

I am trying to run my test script for my todo app in node.js using mocha. But there is a reference error and it says "beforeEach is not defined"

```
const {app} = require('./../server');
const {Todo} = require('./../models/todo');

beforeEach((done) => {
  Todo.remove({}).then(() => done());
});

describe('POST /todos', () => {
  it('should create a new todo', (done) => {
    var text = 'Test todo text';

request(app)
  .post('/todos')
  .send({text})
  .expect(200)
  .expect((res) => {
    expect(res.body.text).toBe(text);
  })
  .end((err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }

    Todo.find().then((todos) => {
      expect(todos.length).toBe(1);
      expect(todos[0].text).toBe(text);
      done();
        }).catch((e) => done(e));
      });
  });

  it('should not create todo with invalid body data', (done) => {
request(app)
  .post('/todos')
  .send({})
  .expect(400)
  .end((err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }

    Todo.find().then((todos) => {
      expect(todos.length).toBe(0);
      done();
    }).catch((e) => done(e));
  });
  });
});
```

Also, I have included all the necessary packages for my package.json file.

My Package.json file is given below

```
{
  "name": "todo-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "mocha server/**/*.test.js",
    "test-watch": "nodemon --exec 'npm test' "
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bluebird": "^3.5.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.5",
    "mongoose": "^4.5.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "expect": "^1.20.2",
    "mocha": "^3.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.10.2",
    "supertest": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try moving the beforeeach into the describe block

Comment: @ninesalt I tried, now I get an error "Describe is  not defined"

Comment: please provide the command you are using to run this test

Comment: @JamshidAsadzadeh I am running this file using node/server/tests/server.test.js command

Comment: I need the full command something like: `mocha node/server/tests/server.test.js` or similar

Comment: Did you try the documentation? https://mochajs.org/#getting-started

Comment: @JamshidAsadzadeh I have configured in my package.json file. as you can see I have attached my code, please refer to my code for the package.json file. The full command is "mocha server/**/*.test.js"

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with these lines `const {app} = require('./../server');
const {Todo} = require('./../models/todo');` try commenting them and using a simple `beforeEach` function it should work just fine

Comment: I don't think it is working, maybe I have some issues with my package.json file?

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul, it looks like you are trying to clear out your todos before you run the next test, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are trying to clear out your data in your MongoDB database before each new test of your todo app. So you want to find your collection of `todo` and drop everything in there before your next test, if so

```
beforeEach(() => {
 mongoose.connection.collections.todo
});
```

With the above you are directly referencing the collection of `todo` sitting inside your database and you call the `drop()` function on your collection of `todo`.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  mongoose.connection.collections.todo.drop();
});
```

Please let me know if I am correct in fulfilling your requirement. Keep in mind this is an asynchronous operation, so you need to ensure you pause the entire testing environment until the operation is complete, but you already know this, because you have already attempted to implement the `done` callback.

Also, `drop()` will accept a callback function like so:

```
beforeEach((done) => {
  mongoose.connection.collections.todo.drop(() => {});
});
```

The function will only be executed once you are done with the collection. So you also have to pass the `done()` callback after defining it like so:

```
beforeEach((done) => {
   mongoose.connection.collections.todo.drop(() => {
     done();
   });
});
```

Also, when you run a Mocha test, you do `npm run test`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to replicate your issue with the test with simple repository using your `package.json` file. My test file

```
const expect = require('expect');

beforeEach((done) => {
  done();  
});

describe('just a test', function() {
  it('test', function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  })
});
```

Then, when running `npm t`, the test was executed successfully.

[image]

Perhaps there is a misconfiguration in your project.

Comment: I am still not being able to figure it out my issue. What should be my approach if there is a certain misconfiguration in my file and I need to find that out?

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul if you can put your project somewhere that I can access, maybe I can help to take a look at it.

Comment: Yes please, I have uploaded my project on Github. please have a look. Here is my link for the GitHub    https://github.com/abhinav-anshul/node-course-2-todo-api

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul I cloned your repo and do `npm install` then `npm test`. The test ran successfully. I couldn't reproduce your issue. My node version 6.7.0.

Comment: I did the same and my test ran successfully and my mocha test cases showed positive results, But when I try to run through "node server/tests/server.test.js" I get that beforeEach reference error. Any ideas what this is happeneing.

Comment: @AbhinavAnshul using `node ....` won't work because `beforeEach` is Mocha function so we need to execute it from `mocha server/tests/server.test.js` instead `node server/tests/server.test.js`. Why do you want to run `node server/tests/server.test.js`?